# Validation of REST endpoint parameter vs. LocalDate with custom validation

Tags: java, validation, spring-boot, bean-validation, hibernate-validator

I've built a REST Service using Spring Boot. At one of the endpoints I have a date posted a request parameter together with 2 other parameters. After the posting the request parameters are binded to an object. The date is binded against a `LocalDate` field. After the posting but before the binding I like to validate the request parameters using validation and Hibernate Validator. There is no available validation for `LocalDate` and I therefor need to write a custom validation for `LocalDate`.

This is what gets posted to the endpoint:

```
/parameter-dates?parameterDateUnadjusted=2017-02-29&limit=5&direction=d
```

Here is the code for the endpoint:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/parameter-dates")
public ResponseEntity getParameterDates(@Valid ParameterDateRequest parameterDateRequest, Errors errors) {
// DO SOME STUFF
}
```

Here is the model used for the object:

```
@Component
@Data
public class ParameterDateRequest {

    @MyDateFormatCheck(pattern = "yyyy-MM-dd", message = "Date not matching")
    LocalDate parameterDateUnadjusted;
    @NotEmpty(message = "Direction can't be empty")
    String direction;
    @Digits(integer=1, fraction=0, message = "Limit has to be an integer of max 100 000")
    int limit;
}
```

This is the code for the validation annotation:

```
@Target({ FIELD, METHOD, PARAMETER, ANNOTATION_TYPE })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = MyDateFormatCheckValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface MyDateFormatCheck {
    String pattern();
    String message();

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

This the code for the validation it self:

```
public class MyDateFormatCheckValidator implements ConstraintValidator<MyDateFormatCheck, LocalDate> {

    private MyDateFormatCheck check;

    @Override
    public void initialize(MyDateFormatCheck constraintAnnotation) {
        this.check = constraintAnnotation;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(LocalDate object, ConstraintValidatorContext constraintContext) {
        if (object == null) {
            return true;
        }

        return isValidDate(object, check.pattern());
    }

    public static boolean isValidDate(LocalDate inDate, String format) {
        // TEST IF inDate IS VALID RETURN TRUE/FALSE
    }
}
```

Is this the wrong approach? I guess the `parameterDateUnadjusted` is actually a `String` rather than a `LocalDate` when it gets posted to the endpoint and then my validator should use a `String` as the `inDate` but then I need to change my model for `parameterDateUnadjusted` to String which doesn't work for the program as it is using it as `LocalDate`. I'm not really sure what do to here. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm in the same boat.  Happen to figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is - [DateTimeFormat](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) annotation. There's no point in validating the date format when the value is already binded to `LocalDate`.